# D3 css not applied when change class

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a bar chart and I want to change the colour when I click over a bar. I want to do this setting a CSS class on the clicked element. Everything work except that the fill style (the colour of the bar clicked) does not change, but the green stroke is applied. And I don't understand why.

This is a screen before and after having clicked on the last bar of the chart
[image]

And this is what I want to achieve
[image]

This is a part of my code, any suggestions?

**JS**

```js
//CREATE THE BAR CHART
var bars = d3
  .select("#bars")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data);

bars
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.year);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.cost);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d.cost);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.cost);
  });

//EVENT ON CLICK
d3.select("#bars")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .on("click", function() {
    //reset the previus bar selected
    d3.select("#bars")
      .select(".selected")
      .classed("selected", false)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.cost);  //reset the original color
      });
    //set the current bar as selected
    d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
  });
```

**CSS**

```css
.selected {
  fill: red;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, attribute styles get overwritten by CSS styles using a selector, which in turn get overwritten by inline CSS styles.

- `.attr("fill", "blue")` sets the attribute `fill="blue"`;
- `.selected { fill: "red"; }` applies the style `fill: red;`;
- `.style("fill", "green")` sets the attribute `style="fill: green;"`, an inline style.

If you apply all these to the same element, the last one has precedence. By deselecting a previously selected bar, you give it `.style("fill"`, and thus overrides any potential future styles. I recommend checking whether you really need to apply those styles, and use `.attr()` if you do.

I've added a small showcase below.

```js
let settings = {
  attr: false,
  class: false,
  style: false,
};
draw();

function draw() {
  d3.select("rect")
    .attr("fill", settings.attr ? "red" : null)
    .attr("class", settings.class ? "blue" : "")
    .style("fill", settings.style ? "green" : null);
}

d3.selectAll("[type='checkbox']")
  .on("change", function() {
    settings[this.getAttribute("id")] = this.checked;
    draw();
  });
```

```css
.blue {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="attr"/><label for="attr">attr</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="class"/><label for="class">class</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="style"/><label for="style">style</label>
</div>
<svg>
  <rect width="30" height="30"></rect>
</svg>
```